# output clustered similarity matrix

Tags: r, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering

I have generated a pearson similarity matrix and plotted the results using pheatmap (clustered using hclust, method = "complete"). I'd like to output the ordered matrix, but in R the default seems to be just to alphabetize everything.

Here is my code:

```
df <- cor(t(genes), method = "pearson")  
pheatmap(df, clustering_method = "complete")
```

head(genes)

```
       pre           early          mid            late       end
AAC1   2.0059007     3.64679740     3.0092533      2.4936171  2.2693034
AAC3  -1.6843969    -1.62572636    -0.7654462     -1.5827481 -1.6059080
AAD10  2.6012529     2.05759631     1.3665322      1.4590833  0.3778324
AAD14  0.5047704     0.76021375     0.1825944      0.6111774  0.1174208
AAD15  7.6017557     8.52315453     7.2605744      6.9029452  5.9028824
AAD16  1.2018193    -0.03285354     0.2229450     -0.1337033  0.2198542
```

This what the current output (df) looks like:

```
     A     B     C    D  
A    1   0.5  0.25  0.1  
B  0.1     1   0.1  0.5    
C  0.5   0.2     1  0.2  
D    0   0.1   0.7    1
```

How can I output the similarity matrix as ordered by hclust?

I've looked, but I haven't been able to find anything that quite accomplishes what I need. Thanks in advance for your help!

(also sorry I don't know how to properly format everything yet)

EDIT: maybe some visuals would help. My clustered pheatmap output looks like this: [ordered heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9zeF.jpg)

I can see groups of genes that behave similarly, but because there are so many it's impossible/useless to read the labels. I want to find out which genes cluster together, but I can't output the ordered matrix.

When I plot the data without clustering it looks like this: [unclustered heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQrRu.jpg)

So the output/data I can get is pretty much useless for further analysis.

Comment: How do you want it ordered? Writing out the desired output would be best. Also please add some more code formatting to the current output, which is difficult to read (Ctrl+k is your friend).

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what the output will look like because I don't have the clustered output (just a png of the heatmap). I just know it isn't alphabetical.

Comment: OK, it'll be difficult to answer without a better understanding of the desired result. Can you provide some sample data so that the problem can be reproduced (i.e. a simulated version of `genes`)?